# Fluent Email SendGrid provider inconsistent behaviour when sending emails in Azure Web App

Tags: email, sendgrid

I have the following method uses the Fluent Email SendGrid provider to send an email

```
public async void GenerateEmail(string recipientEmail, string title, string tagName, string messageBody)
        {
            var email = _email
            .To(recipientEmail)
           .Subject(title)
           .Tag(tagName)
           .Body(messageBody);
           await _email.SendAsync();
        }
```

When my code is run locally all emails are sent, however when attempting to send emails from my Azure web app API the emails are only successfully sent to my personal gmail account. I have attempted to send emails to 2 different emails (a gmail and hotmail, both of which work when ran locally) but no email is sent. I don't even see any data in the Sendgrid activity logs.

I am currently using the free plan on SendGrid with no dedicated IP and I have read this could cause an issue but I would at least expect to see the emails show in the bounced data in Sendgrid but I see no record of them.

Just wondered if anyone else has ran into a similar issue before I upgrade my package in Sendgrid to see if that resolves the issue?

Comment: Are you using an email address that you have either [verified as a single sender](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) or [authenticated the domain](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication)?

Comment: @philnash yeah ive done both of those and also verified link branding. Im not even seeing any emails being sent to those accounts in either the activity or supression data.

Comment: Is there an issue in that you’re not catching potential errors from calling `SendAsync`?

Comment: Added a catch for any errors to the method but even when an email isnt sent i dont receive an error. It seems to be very inconsistent, some emails are sent successfully then others just seem to disappear and are neither received by the recipient or shown in the bounced data

Comment: Maybe check [something like this](https://www.mail-tester.com/) with your emails.